# Unable to change default log apache diretory

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

I would like to change the default directory of apache server:

```
# mkdir new_log
# chmod 755 -R new_log/
# chown -R apache:root new_log/
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/new_log(/.*)?"
# restorecon -v -R -F  /new_log
```

but the service httpd not works due to denied permission to write in this directory.

```
# ls -Z
drwxr-xr-x. apache root   system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 new_log
```

Comment: Is it SELinux related? E.g. do you have the same problems when temporarily setting `setenforce Permissive`?

Comment: No, if I disable with setenforce 0 all works

Comment: Could it be that some logfiles are supposed to be written in a non-existant subdirectory of ./newlog?